# Eclipse code assist show me a bad documentation format

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Eclipse code assist show me a bad documentation format. Image:

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as a known Eclipse bug which has been fixed in the web tools 3.2 stream (this is the Eclipse 3.6 version of web tools so it will be released sometimes this summer). See [bug 277530](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=277530) for details.